# Hypanthial disc

Tags: botany, flowers, morphology

Can anyone illustrate what the hypanthial disc is?  It is descriped throughout the key to *Rosa* in the Flora of North America.  I think that I understand that the hypanthium is the hip which is formed from fused flower parts.  But, which part is the disc.